# How to install nodejs from tar.xz file in Redhat linux machine?

Tags: node.js, linux, redhat, node-modules

I have a "node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz" file which i want to install in a redhat linux machine, The linux machine doesnt have the internet connectivity.Thanks for your your help.

Comment: use `rpm` to install nodejs instead

Comment: Unless he doesn't have local repositories, he won't be able to use `rpm`.

Comment: @Sandy: you should untar the archive (`tar xfJ node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`) and read the containing `INSTALL` or `README` file that is included in most packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below command and its working fine now.

```
tar -xf node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1
```